# grep's output is split by colon when being saved into array

Tags: bash, grep, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, text-parsing

I have a file with array looking like

```
{
    [commandA]: cmdA,
    [commandB]: cmdB,
...
}
```

I'd like to fetch the lines with commands by grep and store them in the bash array. But when I do

```
cmdFunMap=(`grep "^    \[command" myfile`)
printf '%s\n' "${cmdFunMap[@]}"
```

I get

```
[commandA]:
cmdA,
[commandB]:
cmdB,
```

instead of needed

```
[commandA]: cmdA,
[commandB]: cmdB,
```

I tried to match the whole line like

```
cmdFunMap=(`grep "^    \[command.*$" myfile`)
printf '%s\n' "${cmdFunMap[@]}"
```

and set IFS to \n, but the result was the same.

Bash v5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (**WSL**).

How can I fix this colon separation?

**Upd:** checked in Alpine 3.15.4, behavior is just the same.

Comment: Simply `grep '^\[command' Input_file` should work. You have given space before matching `[` that's why its not giving anything.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 , no, I have 4 spaces in front of each 'command'. But thanks, gotta fix it in the question :)

Comment: You should try like `grep -E '^[[:space:]]+\[command'  Input_file` for edited samples.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, nope, cmdFunMap[0] is still [commandA]:, cmdFunMap[1] = cmdA, etc. :(

While I want cmdFunMap[0] = [commandA]: cmdA,

Comment: With your given sample file it works fine, not sure where and how you are testing it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, tried both in Bash v5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (WSL) and Bash v5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl), Alpine 3.15.4

Comment: How about trying `awk '/^[[:space:]]+\[command/' Input_file` once?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, awk gives just the same output :D Maybe it's about Unix env settings? I tried changing IFS to \n, but it did nothing...

Comment: Really not sure for me its working for my machine. Check once `cat -vet Input_file` on your file if you see any control M characters there?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, the lines look like    [commandA]: cmdA,$ , nothing extra.

Comment: is it json? If it is, or if you have the power to make it real json, there are better tools for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You populate your array with 4 words while you'd like to populate it with 2 lines. Use `mapfile`, instead. By default it creates one array entry per line:

```
$ mapfile -t cmdFunMap < <(grep "^    \[command" myfile)
$ printf '%s\n' "${cmdFunMap[@]}"
    [commandA]: cmdA,
    [commandB]: cmdB,
```

Note: don't try to pipe `grep` to `mapfile` instead of using a process substitution (`<( ... )`), it doesn't work and is a common misuse of pipes (and `mapfile`).

Note: you can obtain the same with `IFS`:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' cmdFunMap=(`grep "^    \[command" myfile`)
$ printf '%s\n' "${cmdFunMap[@]}"
    [commandA]: cmdA,
    [commandB]: cmdB,
```

The `$` in `IFS=$'\n'` is probably the difference with what you tried, see the `QUOTING` section of the bash manual for the details.

Comment: That helped, thanks! Don't you know why Bash splits strings in array by the colon, by tha way?

Comment: It doesn't. It splits on space-separated words where spaces are blanks, tabs or newlines. That's why the colons are still there in your array while spaces are not.

Comment: Ah, I see, removed intermediate spaces from input, and my first ever grep solution worked. But your answer above seems better for the task, so I'll work with it. Thanks again!

Comment: See my last edit with `IFS`...